# Postman - Cant run pm.sendRequest() in collection level test script

Tags: javascript, postman

I am trying to compare two different version responses using lodash in postman. When i try to call api in older version using pm.sendRequest(). It's not passing request body which is already available in postman. Its empty. Below is the snippet which i am using.

```
var request = {
                    url: pm.variables.get("host")+pm.request.url.getPathWithQuery(),
                    method: pm.request.method,
                    header: pm.request.headers.toString(),
                    body: pm.request.body.toString()
};
pm.sendRequest(request, function(err, res){
  console.log(res.code);
});
```

Comment: This is showing 1 side of what's happening here and isn't showing the output. What does this request look like in the console? Are there any error messages? Attach some screenshots to show people what you're doing. Without more context and information you're not going to get the answers you seek.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = {
                    url: pm.request.url,
                    method: pm.request.method,
                    header: pm.request.headers,
                    body: pm.request.body
};
pm.sendRequest(request, function(err, res){
  console.log(res);
});
```

You don't have to convert it to string , you can use it as it is .